# "ERROR:malformed array literal" when using json_to_record with a JSON array element in Postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json

This illustrates the issue nicely:

When column b is of type text, and not an array, the following works:

```
select * 
from json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":["hello", "There"],"c":"bar"}') 
    as x(a int, b text, d text);

 a |         b          | d
---+--------------------+---
 1 | ["hello", "There"] |
```

But if I define the `b` column as an array, I get this error:

```
select * 
from json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":["hello", "There"],"c":"bar"}') 
    as x(a int, b text[], d text)

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["hello", "There"]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

How can I convince/coerce `json_to_record` (or `json_populate_record`) to convert a JSON array into the Postgres array of the target column type?

Answer (score 8):

Just a slight variation to Chris's answer:

```
SELECT a, translate(b, '[]', '{}')::text[] AS b, d
FROM json_to_record('{"a": 1, "b": ["hello", "There"], "c": "bar"}')
AS x(a int, b text, d text);
```

The idea is the same: massage the JSON array into an array - in this case, through an array literal.  In addition to a bit cleaner looking code (though I love it, regex usually does not help much in this regard :), it seems slighly faster, too:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonb_test (
    id serial,
    data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO jsonb_test (id, data)
SELECT i, format('{"a": %s, "b": ["foo", "bar"], "c": "baz"}', i::text)::jsonb 
FROM generate_series(1,10000) t(i);

SELECT a, string_to_array(regexp_replace(b, '\[*\"*\s*\]*','','g'),',') AS b, d
FROM jsonb_test AS j, 
LATERAL json_to_record(j.data::json) AS r(a int, b text, d text);

-- versus 

SELECT a, translate(b, '[]', '{}')::text[] AS b, d
FROM jsonb_test AS j, 
LATERAL json_to_record(j.data::json) AS r(a int, b text, d text);
```

On this dataset and on my test box, the regex version shows and average execution time of **300 ms**, while my version shows **210 ms**.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it will fix your issues...

```
SELECT a,string_to_array(regexp_replace(b, '\[*\"*\s*\]*','','g'),',') AS b,d
FROM json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":["hello", "There"],"c":"bar"}')
AS x(a int, b text, d text);
```

It's pretty straightforward how it works:

**First**, take the `text` string in `b`, and strip it down to the useful information.  This is done by using `regexp_replace()` as

```
regexp_replace(b, '\[*\"*\s*\]*','','g')
```

to remove all the instances of `[`, `"`, `]`, and any whitespace characters, or more specifically, to replace any instances of these characters with `''`, and to apply this globally, signalled by using the flag `'g'`.

**Next**, simply split the string to an array using `string_to_array()` as

```
string_to_array(your_string,',')
```

where in this case `your_string` is simply the result of the above `regexp_replace()`. The second argument `','` indicated to `string_to_array()` that the items are comma-separated.

This will yield a `text[]` field containing your desired entries.